# How to set background adapter color to #046697 (light blue) in searchview

Tags: android, styles

Here is my style.xml (I have to use theme.Test style ). I m having trouble in setting the collapseActionView background color and searchview background color if i use app base theme as astyle to my test theme then all the text view background color changes in whole activity

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- <item name="android:background">#083044</item> -->


    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#083044</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.test" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.test.tabbar.style</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Widget.test.ActionBar.TabBar</item>
    <item name="searchAutoCompleteTextView">@style/SearchViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.test.tabbar.style" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#046697</item>
    <item name="background">#046697</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.test.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">#046697</item>
    <item name="background">#046697</item>
</style>

<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.SearchAutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
    <item name="android:background">#046697</item>
    <item name="background">#046697</item>
</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated on this :)

Thanks

Comment: Use it for particular `TextView`.. Don't define this `style.xml` to each and every `TextView`

Comment: How to so so can u suggest me the code or any link ....... THANX

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your property

`<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>`

in `style.xml` and

`android:background="@color/white">`

in `AndroidManifest.xml`.